# No Viewfinder Box / Blender renders out entire scene

Tags: rendering, camera

So very new here. I must have hit something and now there is no camera viewfinder, and blender wants to render out the entire scene including objects that I have hidden.

Rendered image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Few things come to mind:

You may have pressed <kbd>/</kbd> and entered local view. This will allow you to only view (in the viewport) the objects you had selected when you pressed the key. This does not affect renders or the hidden/shown state of objects.

If you've hidden the objects by pressing the "eye" icon, you've only hidden the objects from the viewport. If you pres the *Filter* button which looks like a funnel, you can see all the restriction toggles.

If you enable the icon with the camera, you'll see that camera icon next to each object. Toggling that will show/hide an object from the render.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed my issue of the hidden image being rendered, however my render is coming out absurdly small. 

![](https://i.imgur.com/6AU2PoK.png)

Comment: Select your camera object, and press 0 on the numpad. This will allow you to enter the camera view. Then, press *G*, then *MMB* and move your mouse up and down to zoom the camera in/out.

Comment: so i'm able now to get to the camera view. Now, if you check out the link i posted above, when i render it basically just renders my view in a single box, vs. rendering at full resolution.